# Spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest

I can't make spring serialize the response when results is array/list .
So when I call `clients` from RestController it does return `[{},{},{}]`, instead of real objects, all other methods works just fine.

```
package com.test.Domain.Client;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;    
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {

    @Column(name = "client_id")
    @Id
    private UUID clientId;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    private Client() {

    }

    private Client(UUID clientId, String name) {

        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Client create(String name)
    {
        return new Client(UUID.randomUUID(), name);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.test.Rest;

import com.test.Domain.Calendar.AppointmentRepository;
import com.test.Domain.Client.Client;
import com.test.Domain.Client.ClientRepository;
import com.test.Domain.Worker.WorkerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @Autowired
    private WorkerRepository workerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;


    @RequestMapping(path = "/client", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void registerClient(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name) {
        this.clientRepository.save(Client.create(name));
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/clientCount", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Long countClient() {
        return this.clientRepository.count();
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Client> clients() {
        List<Client> list = new ArrayList<Client>();
        for (Client client : this.clientRepository.findAll()) {
            list.add(client);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing Serializable in your Client class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson needs Getter and Setter methods in order to serialize the `Client` object properly into JSON. Therefore a list of empty objects is returned and the values for the members are missing. Add them to `Client` and the response should look fine.

Comment: Or annotate the fields with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).

Answer (score 1):

Spring applies first registered applicable by response mime-type `HttpMessageConverter` implementation when serializing the response to `/clients` call. In your case this is some JSON serializer. As you have no JSON configuration specified on `Client` class the default POJO serializing approach is used: reflection scanning of object properties. As mentioned earlier your `Client` class doesn't define any properties (at least getters), so serializer do not detect any.

Please refer to the following article for a more detailed explanation: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html

P.S. Marking method with `@ResponseBody` in `@RestController` annotated class is not necessary as itself is a convenience annotation aggregating `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.